# Code that sanitises user input in Plone

Tags: python, plone, zope

Where can I find, inside Plone or Zope, the code that sanitize text input from users?

That kind of logic that can remove HTMLs, Javascripts and all kind of malicious or unwanted text.

I want to do something like:

```
from plone.someplace.toolbox import sanityseUserInput

def mySanitizer(text):
    text = sanityseUserInput(text)
    # Do my work here
    return text
```

Comment: You mean the clean-up that is applied to richtext fields?

Comment: Yes. And the clean-up that is applied to description fields, and other string fields (title etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All clean-up are manage by portal_transforms. See http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Products.PortalTransforms

By default, it's the safe html that is used for all richtext fields.
If you want a new transform, you can create it and register it.

Comment: Thanks @Jihaisse. I found the HtmlToWebIntelligentPlainText, I think that is going to do the trick.